# ImageIcon can´t change default JOptionPane icon

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, imageicon

I recently got an error at adding an icon, I want to replace default JOptionPane icon with an image but I can´t change the default icon

Here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class JOptionPaneIcon
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
    String c;
    Double z,Dollars;
    try
    {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("convert-units.jpg");
        c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert  the amount of mexican pesos",icon);
        z = Double.parseDouble (c);//se captura la cantidad de kilos 
        Dollars= z /18.42 ; //la cantidad de kilos se multiplican por mil para hacerlos gramos 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You got: " + Dollars + " dollars");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Program got an error","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to go and have a read of the [JavaDocs for `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) and understand what each parameter actually means

I think you want to do something more like...

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert  the amount of mexican pesos", null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null);
```

Which, for me, produces

[image: Icon]

You may also find that `ImageIcon` isn't loading the image.  `ImageIcon(String)` expects that the specified image is located on the file system, in your case, in the working directory.  So you might want to check that.

Personally, I'd recommend using `ImageIO.read` instead, as it will generate a `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason, rather then failing silently

See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Still better to use `ImageIO.read` - as it provides a reason why the image isn't been loaded

Comment: it works but I want to store JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Insert  the amount of mexican pesos",null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null); inside in a String variable

Comment: @IsraelSandoval Read the JavaDocs, it's why they are there *"Returns:
user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input"*

Comment: c = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Inserte la cantidad de Kilos;","Kilos a gramos",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icono,null,null);